# DRF Serializer IntegerField Validation To Make Sure ForeignKey Does Exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've a `ModelSerializer class` which uses an `IntegerField` as a replace for a `ForeingKey` relation.

```py
class CartItemCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ('id', 'product_id', 'quantity')

    def validate_product_id(self, value):
        if not Product.objects.filter(pk=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Product not found')
        return value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        product_id = self.validated_data['product_id']
        cart_id = self.context['cart_id']
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        # product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        cart_item, _ = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            cart_id=cart_id, product=product)
        cart_item.quantity += self.validated_data['quantity']
        cart_item.save()
        self.instance = cart_item
        return self.instance
```

I've two questions about this class, first regarding the code, the `validate_product_id` method does a db call to check if the requested Product object exists and then inside the `save` method there is another call to db to get the same Product again, I think this way is not optimized for querying the same object twice. Is there a better way to check for the existence or raising proper error?
second if I use `get_object_or_404` the amount of code to write will decrease but there is no chance to raise a concise but relevant Error Message, so What do you usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one would use a special field type `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.
You don't even need to manually declare one, as it can be done automatically by the `ModelSerializer`.

```
class CartItemCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'quantity')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        cart_id = self.context['cart_id']
        product = self.validated_data['product']
        cart_item, _ = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            cart_id=cart_id, product=product)
        cart_item.quantity += self.validated_data['quantity']
        cart_item.save()
        self.instance = cart_item
        return self.instance
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: thank you so much. I'm new to drf and the question was because of the video that I'm watching to learn drf. It seem's the teacher is not a very good one(maybe he's a bad one).
he also created three serializers for one CartItem model in order to handle GET/POST/PATCH requests. I think I've wasted my money.

Comment: There are always multiple ways to achieve the same goal. Maybe they wanted to introduce the field-based validation this way (however I would argue there are better examples). Three serializers may also be valid depending on the use case. You can even use 4 - one for `list`, one for `retrieve`, another one for `create` and a separate for `update` (i.e. Orders, where you can submit the order with all details, view a list with a short info, open order details for more data and only edit certain fields).

Comment: yes, thank you. I agree with you, if he's purpose was to introduce the field-based validation that was not a good idea. but he had more mistakes for example he didn't use the `get_or_create` method and instead he wrote a 8 line `try/except` cluse to achive the same goal.